# I am trying to create the Floor while repeating the single Floor-Tile image png

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

Here in this Demo i am changing the wall by repeating the single Wall-Tile png image using JQuery for CANVAS in HTML5.

And Now i want to create a Floor by using just one png of Floor-Tile. But using Skew in css doesn't help here.

is there any jQuery to make it? OR How do i write the JQuery to create a floor using single floor-tile image?

[This is how the page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVaEa.png)
and
[Here is the Floor-Tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROAIo.jpg)

Comment: Instead of css skew, I recommend you to use 3d transform: https://jsfiddle.net/scLaj9m4/ http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp

Comment: Hello, Martin thank you very much for your response.
i've tried this but each Tile have different angles as it has to create a floor.

http://jsfiddle.net/hyLx5g37/

Comment: @ChiragDave Did you make it work? Can you please share the code ?